# Where is a good JavaScript reference for object event handlers?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am relatively new to JavaScript and constantly need to look up how to handle various events for objects.  For example, I have a table containing a few text fields and need to know when somebody starts typing in any of the text boxes.  Is there any good concise reference on the web anyplace that documents all of the objects and event handlers associated with all objects?  I'd like to be able to look up the object and see all of the events I can handle for that object.

Comment: Specifically, the concept of "event delegation" would be a great choice here.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout mozillas javascript ducmentation on `addEventListener` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

and the w3 spec page, section about event flow: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webreference.com/javascript/reference/core_ref/contents.html

http://www.javascript.com/

and later on

[www.jquery.com](http://www.jquery.com)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the events section here:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/contents.html

Answer (score 0):

Event handler properties vary a little between browsers. Check Mozillas documentation, the w3c events specification linked, and MSDN.